# How make uint32 multiplications in javascript like, C makes them

Tags: javascript

How make uint32 multiplications in javascript without loosing precision ?

I am trying implement C algorithm in javascript.

```
uint32 key = (val * 134775813) + 1;
```

So, all higher bytes will be lost in result.

I tried browser console:

```
> a1 = 591751271
591751271
> a2 = 134775813
134775813
> a4 = (a1 * a2) + 1;
79753758642808320
```

I made same calculation with python

```
Python 3.7.9 (default, Aug 18 2020, 06:22:45) 
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a1=591751271
>>> a2=134775813
>>> a4 = (a1 * a2) + 1
>>> print(a4)
79753758642808324
```

Looks similar but I am specially interested those lower bytes. Can anyone point me right direction.

I know there are built in BigInt objects, but really you cant make any operations with those.

Comment: JS numbers are IEEE754-2019 float 64. You should look at [Math.imul](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/imul)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see this function in (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_math.asp) list, but I found it in MDN page.

Comment: Nice but for getting uint32 I can use one liner
const uMul = (a,b) => Math.imul(a, b) >>> 0;

Comment: [w3schools is an absolutely terrible resource](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com/). Best not use them at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [ASDFGerte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6692606/asdfgerte). Who
pointed me towards [Math.imul](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/imul) function.

I came up with this one liner and it performed perfectly.

```js
const uMul = (a,b) => Math.imul(a, b) >>> 0;
```

MDN site has polyfill function and with small change it does the same.

```js
const uMul = (a, b) => {
  const aHi = (a >>> 16) & 0xffff;
  const aLo = a & 0xffff;
  const bHi = (b >>> 16) & 0xffff;
  const bLo = b & 0xffff;
  // the shift by 0 fixes the sign on the high part
  return (aLo * bLo) + (((aHi * bLo + aLo * bHi) << 16) >>> 0);
};
```